# Application error: Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

could you please suggest me on this.

When I try accessing the app link. Following error appears on the page:

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>   If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I created `Procfile`. Still cannot get rid of this error `No web processes running`

**Heroku log**

```
heroku logs --app propertybooking
2014-03-04T00:52:43.027134+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T00:52:43.027229+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T00:56:11+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-03-04T00:57:09.578060+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE resource by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T00:57:09.578139+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T00:57:09.783103+00:00 heroku[api]: Added DATABASE_URL config vars. by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T00:57:09.783179+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T00:57:10.017963+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T00:57:10.017860+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 655bdae by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T00:57:10+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-03-04T00:58:51.300641+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=6b14a96e-064d-4e03-8d1c-a30117bc3db3 fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T00:58:52.238012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=5b9be8ef-7ae4-4a97-b991-1ed424c63061 fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T01:00:32+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-03-04T01:00:58.966318+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 37555ec by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T01:00:58.966395+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T01:00:59+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-03-04T01:05:40.315893+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=85b971b4-77d1-4a99-9f3a-15ead3884ad6 fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T05:46:25.664525+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=1e311ff2-14ee-419c-9352-14494ab48019 fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T06:04:07.023185+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=00de0d3a-b7c6-4cd7-a515-2fb15b7eea6c fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T06:04:06.303166+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=cfbdeb7c-f1fa-4190-b2c3-b5ed4ae1e79b fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T06:05:43.220478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=44e32a61-1d2e-4211-947f-887dfe488a91 fwd="116.255.8.253"
 dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T06:05:42.943163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=577db4cd-6476-4581-8d8e-5531051a6a3d fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T08:39:43+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-03-04T08:40:03.817169+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 2a90b3e by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T08:40:03.817169+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T08:40:03+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-03-04T08:45:07.050460+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=2653335f-e7d8-4ad3-98b2-12331b824c61 fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T08:45:08.025340+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=c09bd3e6-ad75-4ad7-b5c5-673e3e890ac0 fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T08:45:23.510432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=fa120175-7006-471c-8bc2-891a9af4169c fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T08:45:23.848913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=24463d40-e36f-42b1-b73d-755bae86baef fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T08:47:02.732135+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=54bc1ec5-d206-45c3-9bf8-c382cd7cf6bf fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T08:47:03.018363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=2be64be9-2f1f-426f-8505-e5898bb107c9 fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T11:34:18.439139+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=5d559f8c-abc2-4dcf-a61b-c1c256b4e0b5 fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T11:34:18.803386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=610dbb40-289a-4c9c-9f1a-2810c0e4270b fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T13:06:35.850439+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T13:06:35.850348+00:00 heroku[api]: Add PATH config by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T13:12:26+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-03-04T13:12:50.405315+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 23054d0 by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T13:12:50.405444+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by radsrinivasan@gmail.com
2014-03-04T13:12:50+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-03-04T13:13:03.007493+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=2ffa8c80-2f69-4dac-818a-29d142d0bf8b fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T13:13:03.383880+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=e5abe123-4dc2-40f0-8b05-66283a8229b8 fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T13:17:10.478449+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=e2bd5a2a-d0db-4400-8f10-2f8f9df2c701 fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-04T13:17:10.776299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=propertybooking.herokuapp.com request_id=5eef4e4e-c127-4ff9-8ed6-1453a14b4e7f fwd="116.255.8.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

You need to have 'web' entry in your `procfile` - that is the only one Heroku will autostart.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for the suggestion. When I include it I get this error Scaling web dynos... failed.

Comment: Hi John, any suggestion on it?? Procfile contains "web: python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT" .. but I get this error:Scaling dynos... failed
 !    No such process type web defined in Procfile.

Comment: are you sure you've added the procfile to git and pushed it to Heroku? If you do `heroku run bash` and then `cat Procfile` do you see what you'd expect?

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for the suggestion. I hadn't push the update Procfile. It works now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: excellent - don't forget to mark your question answered by clicking on the tick.

Comment: Sure thank you, I shall John.